# How can I read the first n rows of table a based upon the number of rows in table b?

Tags: sql, select, firebird, firebird-3.0, libreoffice-base

I have a table "L20" that contains 1 to 20 values "HDIF" in it, sorted in ascending order. I need to extract the first 1 to 10 of those values into table "T10" depending upon the number of values in table "L20". I'm using Windows 10, Libreoffice 6.4.4, with Firebird 3 database. I've tried the CASE statement and the DECODE statement on the COUNT of rows in "L20", but neither seems to work.

If I put in a numeral for the SELECT on table "L20" then it works correctly. Anyone have an idea of how to solve? The purpose of this query is to calculate a golf handicap which uses [up to] the best (lowest) 10 scores of [up to] the last (most recent) 20 games played. Here is the coding:

```
/* Qry_Index_Calc - calculates handicap index from top 10 differentials of last 20 games  */
/* Source is "VW_Plyr_Diff" which has handicap differentials already calculated. */

SELECT (AVG ("T10"."HDIF") * .96) "Index", (Count ("T10"."HDIF")) FROM

/* Get only the games needed if less than 20 games have been played. */

    (
    SELECT FIRST 

        DECODE ((SELECT COUNT (*) FROM "L20"), 
              1,  1
            , 2,  1
            , 3,  1
            , 4,  1
            , 5,  1
            , 6,  1     
            , 7,  2
            , 8,  2
            , 9,  3
            , 10, 3
            , 11, 4
            , 12, 4
            , 13, 5
            , 14, 5
            , 15, 6
            , 16, 6
            , 17, 7
            , 18, 8
            , 19, 9
            , 10)

    "L20"."HDIF"

    FROM

/*  Get up to 20 of the most recent (last) games played.  */

            ( SELECT FIRST 20 "PlayerID" "PID", "GID" "GID", 
            RANK ( ) OVER ( PARTITION BY "PlayerID" ORDER BY "Diff" ) "Rnk", 
            "Diff" "HDIF", "Date" "Gdate"
            FROM "Vw_Plyr_Diff"
            WHERE "PlayerID" = 1) 

            "L20"   

    ) "T10"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put parentheses around the expression in `FIRST`. As specified in the [Firebird 3.0 Language Reference for `FIRST`, `SKIP`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-dml-select-first-skip):

> ```
> SELECT
>   [FIRST <m>] [SKIP <n>]
>   FROM ...
>   ...
>
> <m>, <n>  ::=
>     <integer-literal>
>   | <query-parameter>
>   | (<integer-expression>)
> ```

So, use

```
select first (decode(...)) ....
```

When using subqueries directly in `first`, you need to use double parentheses (once for the expression, and once for the fact that sub-queries in expressions are enclosed in parentheses.

The SQL standard [`OFFSET`/`FETCH`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-dml-select-offsetfetch) clauses introduced in Firebird 3 do not support expressions.

Beware, your current code doesn't specify an `ORDER BY`, this means it is undefined exactly which rows are returned, it will depend on location of data inside the database, the access plan, etc. I would recommend that you add an appropriate `ORDER BY` clause to ensure the returned rows are as expected.

It looks like you're trying to `SELECT` from the derived table `L20` defined in the `FROM` clause, and not from an actual table `L20`. If you want to be able to do that, then `L20` most be specified as a [common table expression](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-dml-select-cte).

Comment: Mark, that got it! Thank you! I missed the parentheses issue, and didn't realize what a CTE is, or what it can do. This is my first attempt at SQL and I had been struggling with this for a while. Now that it is solved I can continue to develop the application. Thanks again.

Comment: @BruceReirden You're welcome. If my answer helped you, then please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark.